# What response is reasonable to expect of a school child in the event that they have seen an exam question prior to the exam?

Tags: ethics, exams

[It is in the news](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/education-67123379) that a child was stripped of their exam result after it emerged that while reviewing for the exam, they had found the same question online.  It seems that they were not aware it was going to be on the exam, and that after encountering the question they had asked a teacher for help with it.  It appears the exam expected the pupil to alert them to the issue, and in the absence of this considered it cheating.

I am surprised by this.  It has been a long time since I was at school doing exams, but in pre-internet days I remember going through many past papers and frequently coming across questions that were functionally identical to ones I had tackled previously.  I would never have considered such an event noteworthy, let alone putting a reporting responsibility on me. I certainly cannot remember any instruction to do so.

What is reasonable to expect of a school child in a situation like this?  Are all exam questions unique enough that such reporting makes sense?  Is there a standard practice these days that is provided to children for these situations?  Is there something that I am missing that makes this make more sense?

Comment: Pre-university/college/higher education is not on-topic here.

Comment: Maybe, this question can be answered on "Stack Exchange Parenting".

Comment: I think that this would be considered on-topic if it were rephrased to be about how a university lecturer should handle encountering a similar situation with one of their students, however.